# PHPJoomla 1.7 abstract error

Tags: joomla, phpmyadmin

I have installed xampp's xampp-win32-1.7.4-VC6-installer.exe and went in fine
except the last statment (Of Issue).

Created a MySQL database, and then started installing as to a video Joomla Joomla_1.7.0-Stable-Full_Package.zip in htdocs. And connected it in.

Then as I go to the Joomla site on my surver, abstact erroer

```
Strict Standards: Static function JDatabase::test() should not be abstract in C: \x\htdocs\libraries\joomla\database\database.php on line 350

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C: \x\htdocs\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 394

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C: \x\htdocs\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C: \x\htdocs\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396

[etc.]

Strict Standards: Accessing static property JCache::$_handler as non static in C: \x\htdocs\libraries\joomla\cache\cache.php on line 396
```

Answer (score 2):

it means low skills.

change **$this->_handler**   to **self::$_handler**

in that file. Fin

Answer (score 1):

This means that Joomla doesn't satisfied PHP Strict Standards. You can turn off these errors in your php.ini file

Comment: where i can find that php.ini file

Comment: I do not use wamp. But as far as I remeber it in /wamp/bin/php directory. Also if webserver allows you can put php.ini into the site root only with rules which are to be rewrited.

Answer (score 1):

This is common in joomla also this is not error. This is just warning this will not stop your joomla to stop.

Anyway i will give a solution try this...

> 1. First check for php.ini file in your server folder (XAMPP), in that
>      replace display_errors=false
> 2. Change error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT to error_reporting =
>      E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
> 3. One more thing select the Server (XAMPP) application and right
>      click-> and check for 'run always as administrator'

Regards,

Shanmugam

Comment: Great. If you got it. u can close this thread. please vote for my answer too if it helped you

Comment: where i can find the php.ini file

Comment: Hi Siva you can find php.ini inside C:\xampp\php this path if you have installed Xampp and in default directory

Answer (score 0):

You have "Strict Standards: Non-static method" errors, this is because of the error reporting settings in your `Xampp php.ini` file. In the `php.ini` file make these changes and then restart Apache:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
display_errors = Off
```

You must restart Apache before these changes take effect. If you are unsure where you `php.ini` file is, try running this file on your server and look for the "Loaded Configuration File" line.